# Empty content in a request with python-requests

Tags: python, html, http, web, python-requests

I have bee trying to get the html code of this page. The content of the page is empty but the page is functional ( i can see it in the browser)

```
import requests
print 'Requests version: ', requests.__version__
r = requests.get('https://aidoru-online.org', allow_redirects=True, headers={'User-Agent': 'test'})
print 'Status code: ', r.status_code
print 'Content len: ', len(r.content)
print 'History: ', r.history
```

The result is

```
Requests version:  2.13.0
Status code:  200
Content len:  0
History:  []
```

What can be the cause?

Thank you.

Comment: @PedroLobito this is not his case. I have checked

Comment: You're getting a length of zero because `refresh: 0; url=login.php` header is being sent by the server. https://screenpresso.com/=0Q0sc

Comment: @PedroLobito the history is an empty list ;( i will update the question with this info

Comment: Why don't you request `https://aidoru-online.org/login.php` directly ? It's not clear what you're trying to do.